# Fixed-position columns layout with a minimum width

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to build a layout for a blog-like application having:

- a fixed-position fixed-width header
- fixed-position fixed-width left and right columns
- a scrollable centered fixed-width content

So basically there's a scrollable column in the middle of the page, surrounded by a fixed structure (that doesn't scroll away).

My problem: is there a way to prevent the right column to cover the middle one, if the user resizes the window to be too small? I'd like a scrollbar instead..

Here's what I came up with:

```
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    .header {
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    }

    .left {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    width: 180px;
    }

    .right {
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 180px;
    }

    .content {
    background: grey;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 640px;
    }

    .wrapper {
    padding: 0 180px;
    }
</style>

<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        SCROLLABLE<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(btw, is there a site to share tests like this?)

As you can see, when the window is too small the left and middle column are handled correctly, but the right one may end up covering them... Is there a way to prevent it?

**Edit**: I noticed that the left column has its problems too :/ When the horizontal scrollbar appears and you scroll to the right, the middle column scrolls under the left one... I'm beginning to think I'm going completely the wrong way.. :/

demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/Gr58j/](http://jsfiddle.net/Gr58j/1)

Comment: there is a site http://jsfiddle.net/  ur question: http://jsfiddle.net/Gr58j/

Comment: Thank you :) Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/TqTaE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** to css-only solution:

css:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0;}

.header, .left, .right {position:fixed;}
.header {background:#ff0000;top:0px;left:0;width:100%;height:100px;}

.left, .right {top:100px;width:180px;}
.left {background:#ffff00;left:0}
.right {background:#00ff00;right:0;}

.wrapperOuter {margin:100px 180px 0 180px;}
.wrapper {width:100%;overflow:auto;}
.content {background:#888888;width:640px;margin:0 auto;}
```

html:

```
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="wrapperOuter">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            SCROLLABLE<br/>
            CONTENT<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="right">RIGHT</div>
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

There may be a way to handle this with some css mastery but if you don't mind a little jQuery you can get the desired effect

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/aJPdJ/1/

Tested in IE 8, FF 3.6, Chrome 10

jQuery:

```
var baseContentWidth = 0;
var checkContentSize = function() {
    $availableWidth = $(window).width() - $('.left').width() - $('.right').width();
    $wrapper = $('.wrapper');

    if (baseContentWidth === 0) {
        baseContentWidth = $('.content').width();
    }

    if ($availableWidth < baseContentWidth) {
        $wrapper.css({width: $availableWidth + "px", overflow: "scroll"});
    } else {
        $wrapper.css({width: "", overflow: ""});
    }
};

// Re-check on window resize event
$(window).resize(function() {
    checkContentSize();
});

checkContentSize();
```

css:

```
body {margin:0;padding:0;}

.header, .left, .right {position:fixed;}
.header {background:#ff0000;top:0px;left:0;width:100%;height:100px;}

.left, .right {top:100px;width:180px;}
.left {background:#ffff00;left:0}
.right {background:#00ff00;right:0;}

.wrapper {margin:0 180px;}
.content {background:#888888;margin:100px auto 0 auto;width:640px}
```

html:

```
<div class="header">HEADER</div>
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        SCROLLABLE<br/>
        CONTENT<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>
```

while this may be a solution to your layout issue personally I wouldn't want to use jquery as a layout dependency so perhaps there is some better way to handle this with just css.  Additionally, one of the various layouts on this site [Float-less CSS layout](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/css-layout/no_div_no_float_no_clear_no_hack_no_joke.asp) may get you what you need.

Comment: I've spent hours trying to solve this problem using just CSS, I fear the only way is the javascript one.. :( Unless there's a site out there to ask questions to a "CSS guru".. X-)

Comment: Hah, think I got the css only solution by adding an outer wrapper div http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/aJPdJ/3/